# Divs of same ID overlap

Tags: html, css, position

I have two divs on my page and have given them both the class "nav".

Here is my CSS:

```
.nav {
 border-radius: 1em;
 background-color: #0000BB;
 color: white;
 padding: 1em;
 position: absolute;//Fits size to content.
 margin: 1em;   
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%);
 display: block
}
```

I want these two divs which have the same format to appear one after another in the order they appear in my HTML, however, for some reason they are appearing directly on top of one another. Shouldn't the "display: block" attribute prevent this from happening however?

EDIT: Updated CSS from ID to class.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique. Also you need to provide a [mcve], not just one CSS rule. And absolutely positioned elements are positioned with respect to their closest positioned ancestor. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning

Comment: change the id to a class  - as @j08691 says - id's must be unique.

Comment: The issue persists if I change them to classes as well.

Comment: @j08691 Thanks for the documentation. It's difficult for me to post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example as I don't want to have to post the code from my entire document or CSS stylesheet.

In general, how would one go about positioning two elements, one above the other, using the same CSS class. I have them set at "position: absolute" for the notated reason that I want the div size to match it's content. I cannot seem to get it them to stop overlapping unless I change this however and am now at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are using the property "Position: absolute", which means the "display" property wont work, try using position:'relative' instead.

Comment: and in your case use classes instead of ID's

Comment: I've tried that, however I want the divs to only be as large as their content and with position:'relative' the divs span the entire width of the page.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle with your current code? @BrandonH.

Comment: Issue resolved. I ended up creating a container div which centers content and then created the divs I wanted within those containers to match the size. Seems to be working for now...